# modx - Using a dynamic ID in gerResourceField

Tags: modx

I need to use a 'start id' that is set as a TV in a specific resource.

This is the basic call i'm trying to make dynamic:

1

```
[[getResourceField? &id=`298` &field=`longtitle`]]
```

It seems that i can not nest another getResourceField to get this working:

```
[[getResourceField? &id=`[[!getResourceField? &id=`[[*photoGalleryId]]` &field=`albumStart` &processTV=`1`]]` &field=`longtitle`]]
```

I've also tried putting ID collector as a separate chunk which also fails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with getResourceField - but can you not just place the TV in the ID?

```
[[getResourceField? &id=`[[*photoGalleryId]]` &field=`longtitle`]]
```

it kind of looks to me like you want to do this instead?

```
[[getResourceField? &id=`[[*photoGalleryId]]` &field=`albumStart` &processTV=`1` &field=`longtitle`]]
```

If you are trying to use the photoGalleryId TV of the ~current~ resource, if you are trying to get it from a different resource you will need a snippet.

Comment: Thanks Sean, it was referencing an unrelated resoure so the TV was not accessible: it just needed the second call to be uncached. Check out getResourceField - speeds things when you only want one field.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this it required the second snippet to be called uncached (without the !):

```
[[getResourceField? &id=`[[getResourceField? &id=`[[*photoGalleryId]]` &field=`albumStart` &processTV=`1`]]` &field=`longtitle`]]
```